# Is it okay for UVs to touch border?

Tags: uv-mapping

As a matter of habit I always shrink UVs to just below the full texture space, even for single island things like sprites. Can I have my UVs touching the actual border or is this bad practice?

Comment: Do you mean using the space from 0,0 up to 1,1? If yes, there's really no problem in doing so. If you use it to texture quads (eg. for sprites), that's how you should do it.

Answer (score 1):

UVs touching the border is pretty routine. However a related thing you probably want to know about is repeating vs. clamp texture; the idea is to set the image so that borders are rendered correctly.